# Getting "Type Initialization Exception "

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

[image: cal stack of exception]

I am getting type initialization exception at below line.

```
var path = InputOptions.downloadsPath;
```

`InputOptions` is a class I wrote. It contains this:

```
public static readonly string parentpath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).ToString();
public static readonly string downloadsPath = parentpath + @"\DATA\Download";
```

Comment: getting error while assigning  value to "path" variable.

Comment: Why would you be able to reassign a readonly value? Wouldn't that defeat the point of it being readonly?

Comment: It´s completely unclear what you are asking. In particular your minimalistic code doesn´t help much to reproduce your issue. It doesn´t even compile. Could you please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i have edited question  and I am not reassigning value .

Comment: Is it  understandable now ??

Comment: Please add your full stack trace of the exception. The exception would normally tell you which "Type" has failed. It is more likely you have some missing dependent assemblies.

Comment: In a web application, "Current directory" doesn't make sense, most likely you're getting a crash related to you trying to navigate to the parent of something which you don't have access to, or you're already at the root, etc. You should use `Server.MapPath` to locate your download folder.

Comment: i have added call stack in question  now.

Comment: Add full `InputOptions` class